# Symfony error when inserting a foreign key

Tags: symfony

I am trying to INSERT into a table which has a foreign key, and I get the following error:

Argument 4 passed to App\Entity\Builds::__construct() must be an instance of App\Entity\Usuarios, int given

I understand that the foreign key, which is an id, has to be an INT but the error tells me that it has to be an instance of App\Entity\Users.

Code:

```
public function guardarBuild(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        $data = $request->request->all();
        $this->controlSesion();
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $session = new Session();
        $idUsu = $entityManager->getRepository(Usuarios::class)->findOneBy(['usuario' => $session->get('usuario'), 'password' => $session->get('password')]);
        $idUsuario = $idUsu->getId(); 
        $nuevaBuild = new Builds(
            $data['nombre'], 
            $data['descripcion'], 
            0, 
            $idUsuario //foreign key
        );
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($nuevaBuild);
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        return new JsonResponse(['status' => 'Build creada'],Response::HTTP_CREATED);
    }
```

Comment: in an ORM, you don't really have "ids" of related entities, instead, you assign the entity. so instead of `$idUsuario` in your `//foreign key` line, try `$idUsu` (which probably should be called `$usuario`, but that's probably besides the point). doctrine knows how to handle the obect and will assign its id to the database column accordingly.

Comment: also in doctrine (and most other ORMs) it's common to make the entity name singular.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine [recommends against](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.8/reference/best-practices.html#don-t-map-foreign-keys-to-fields-in-an-entity) using hard foreign key values to manage entity associations, and suggests using object references instead. Aka, have `Builds::__construct` expect a `Usuarios` instance as its fourth argument instead of a (foreign key) `int` value.